# Get params from outside of route component in React Router 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have created 2 components named `Layout` and `Homepage`. Then I have added `Layout` in return and implement 2 route inside it with `Homepage` component. Now am trying to get `params` by `useParams` hook inside `Layout` component while I am in the location of `/10`. Is it possible? It is giving blank in my side.

`App.js`

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
        <Route path="/:id" element={<Homepage />} />
      </Routes>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

`Layout.js`

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  console.log(params);
  return(
    <div>
      Hello World
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you currently on an "/someIdValue" path for there to be a route param to pick up?

Comment: Yeah. Now I am in `/10`. But getting blank object in `param`

Comment: If `App.js` is the root component of your app, you are missing a `Router` object (`BrowserRouter`, `HashRouter` etc) above `Layout`

Comment: @ColdAtNight If there were no `Router` then there'd be errors trying to use the `useParams` hook and rendering routes.

Comment: I've `Index.js` as the root component in my app, where I have wrapped `App.js` component by `BrouserRouter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The `Layout` component is rendered *outside* the `Routes` component that manages the route matching and route params it renders.

## Solution

The common pattern for rendering layouts is to render the layout component into a route and have the layout render an `Outlet` for its nested routes to be rendered out on.

```
const Layout = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ id });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Hello World
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes output here
    </div>
  );
};
```

Routes

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route path=":id" element={<Homepage />} /> // <-- rendered into outlet
    <Route index element={<Homepage />} />      // <-- rendered into outlet
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit get-params-from-outside-of-route-component-in-react-router-6]

Comment: Is there a similar solution for version 5 ?

Comment: @OleksandrFomin What do you need a solution for in RRDv5?

Comment: I need to access URL params from outside the route in a layout component

Comment: @OleksandrFomin Would the [useRouteMatch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) be helpful then? If not, then it may be for the best that you post an entirely new question on SO with supporting [mcve]. If you do this then please feel free to ping me in another comment here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.